# TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str Python sentiment tweet

Tags: python, json, tweepy, sentiment-analysis, urllib3

I am trying to capture real live tweets. I am trying to access contents using the json library, and create new objects and append this into a list.

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import tweepy

import json
import urllib.parse
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

# Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = "C"
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
sentDexAuth = ''


auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)



def sentimentAnalysis(text):
    encoded_text = urllib.parse.quote(text)
    API_Call = 'http://sentdex.com/api/api.php?text=' + encoded_text + '&auth=' + sentDexAuth
    output = urlopen(API_Call).read()

    return output

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def __init___(self):
        self.tweet_data = []


def on_data(self, data):
    tweet = json.loads(data)
    for x in tweet.items():
        sentimentRating = sentimentAnalysis(x['text'])
        actualtweets = {
            'created_at' : x['created_at'],
            'id' : x['id'],
            'tweets': x['text'] + sentimentRating
        }
        self.tweet_data.append(actualtweets)


    with open('rawtweets2.json', 'w') as out:
        json.dump(self.tweet_data, out)

    print(tweet)
l = StdOutListener()
stream = Stream(auth, l)
keywords = ['iknow']
stream.filter(track=keywords)
```

I believe that i am accessing the json objects correctly however i am not sure of this error, i need it to be a string for my sentiment function to work, and 
iam getting a type error:

```
sentimentRating = sentimentAnalysis(x['text'])
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: It seems that your `x` is a tuple,so you can't use `x['text']`.Try to print `x` or debug your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here,

```
for x in tweet.items():
        sentimentRating = sentimentAnalysis(x['text'])
```

`x` is a tuple of your dictionary's `(key,value)`so you have to pass index.

if you simply want the data of `'text'` key. you can write `tweet['text']`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `x` is tuple, so you need to use numeric indexes like `x[1]`, not strings.